# ROS navigation can't rotate 180°

Tags: ros, navigation, planner, amcl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ,
i'm getting some trouble with the dwa_local planner it's seems that my robot can follow path and avoid obstacle but  when i choose a goal that makes the robot turn in the oposite direction   it starts to turn in place about 60 degrees and then start to move forward and then loose the path , why it's does not turn 90 degrees ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293116/ros-navigation-can%27t-rotate-180%C2%B0/) by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pengjiawei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31790/pengjiawei/) on 2018-06-04**:
what does your configuration of base_local_planner look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i found the problem and it's not the local_planner but there is a lag between laser data and the map , the localization is not good at all

---

Originally posted by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) with karma: 58 on 2018-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-07-03**:
how do you fix this lag? what are the parameters I should be looking at?

**Comment by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on 2018-07-04**:
my odometry was bad  specially when turning  , have a look to [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide)  to check if nothing is wrong with your configuration

**Comment by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on 2018-07-24**:
@aarontan check also your local planner config  , the parameter  max_vel_theta   and  min_in_place_vel_theta   should not be too much  different